# Почему этот код в LibreOffice Basic не работает, как надо?

Tags: libre-office, basic, libre-office-calc

Есть такой код:

```
function getcell(width&, value&) as String
dim result$
for i = 0 to width - len("" & value)
    result = result & " "
next

result = result & ("" & value)

getcell = result
end function
```

Функция должна возвращать ячейку с числом, а получается пустая строка

Comment: По самому вопросу ничего не могу сказать, а вот форматировать с ведущими пробелами можно с помощью формата с использованием символа `?`, который заменяется на пробел. Например, формат `????` означает форматировать число, добавляя слева пробелы до ширины 4.